# What is wrong in my proof for "every linearly compact module is Artinian"

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, artinian

We know that every artinian module is linearly compact but the converse is not true. But i can proof the converse!!

By a theorem, a module $M$ is artinian iff every each of quotient modules is finitely cogenerated. (Algebras, Rings and Modules, Volume 1. Michiel Hazewinkel, Nadiya Gubareni, V.V. Kirichenko. Prop. 3.1.6)

On the other hand we know that every linearly compact module is finitely cogenerated. (
Modules over Non-Noetherian Domains, L. Fuchs and Luigi Salce, Lemma 7.3).

Also every quotient module of a linearly compact module is linearly compact.(Foundation of module and rings, robert Wisbauer. 29.8)

Hence, every quotient module of a linearly compact module is finitely cogenerated and proof is complete!

What is wrong in this proof. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Here is Lemma 7.3 page 298 of L. Fuch' book.

Lemma 7.3. A module that is linearly compact in the discrete topology is finitely cogenerated, so it has finite Goldie dimension.It also has finite dual Goldie dimension.

Comment: Can you please state fully Lemma 7.3 in the Fuchs-Salce book?

Comment: It's false that a linearly compact module (in the discrete topology) is finitely cogenerated. For instance $F[[x]]$ (the ring of formal power series over the field $F$) is linearly compact in the discrete topology, but is clearly not finitely cogenerated, since it has zero socle.

Comment: I mailed the second author of the book, who happens to be a friend of mine. Please, when you cite a work, name *all* the authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed in an email from the book's second author, the statement of Lemma 7.3 is incorrect; it should only say that a linearly compact module (with the discrete topology) has finite Goldie dimension and codimension.
(This part is correct.)

There are several counterexamples to the statement that a linearly compact module is finitely cogenerated. The simplest one is the ring $F[[x]]$ of formal power series over the field $F$, which is a complete local ring, hence linearly compact in every linear topology, including the discrete one, by a result of [Zelinsky](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372616): *Linearly Compact Modules and Rings*, American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 75, No. 1 (Jan., 1953), pp. 79–90.

[image]

Note that $F[[x]]$, as a module over itself, is not finitely cogenerated, having zero socle.

Answer (score 1):

No, you misread the conditions of Fuchs' lemma $7.3$ (page 298). It doesn't say that *any* linearly compact module is finitely cogenerated. What the lemma says is that if a module is linearly compact in the *discrete* topology, then it's finitely cogenerated.

Thus, what you've proved is that a module is artinian if and only if it's linearly compact in the discrete topology.

Comment: but it seems that the notion of linearly compact with discrete topology in Fuch's book is the same as linearly compact in Wisbauer's book. isn't it?

Comment: but it seems that the notion of linearly compact with discrete topology in Fuch's book is the same as linearly compact in Wisbauer's book. isn't it? thanks

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't prove the claim. You want to show that an arbitrary linearly compact module is finitely cogenerated. Fuchs' lemma gives you that if the topology is _discrete_. The definition of "linear compact module" depends on the topology, but for an _arbitrary_ linear compact module, the topology is not necessarily discrete. Thus, your argument doesn't work.

Comment: Well, a complete local ring (the $p$-adic integers, for instance) is linearly compact in the discrete topology (Zelinsky (1953), see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372616 for the article, Theorem 3).

Comment: See also example 1.13 in http://www.numdam.org/article/RSMUP_1991__85__147_0.pdf together with the classical result by Müller that a ring with Morita duality is linearly compact in the discrete topology.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Well, there is some example of linearly compact modules in the discrete topology that are not Artinian. But what about my proof? what is wrong? Is Lemma 7.3 of Fuch's book mistake? thanks for good comments. Can help me more?

Comment: @SAliMousavi I asked you to state precisely Lemma 7.3: I'm sure that László and Luigi didn't write a false lemma. If not, I know where the second author lives, in the same town as I. `;-)`

Comment: @quasi Thanks. But by egreg's comment, every complete local ring in discrete topology is linearly compact. I could not find mistake of my proof and i am confused! Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: @egreg excuse me. I didn't see your comment. Here this lemma. Lemma 7.3 page 298. A module that is linearly compact in the discrete topology is finitely cogenerated, so it has finite Goldi dimension.

Comment: @SAliMousavi Please, add it to your question. *Full* statement, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57164/discussion-between-s-ali-mousavi-and-egreg).